# filter table mysql using multiple colums also between

Tags: php, mysql, filtering, between, sql-like

how to join **BETWEEN** statement and **AND** statement using multiple category?

```
SELECT * FROM quick_inquiry WHERE inquiry_time BETWEEN '$start' AND  '$end' AND
  inquiry_language LIKE '%$language%' AND
  service_country LIKE '%$country%' AND
  category LIKE '%$category%' AND
  replied LIKE '%$replied%'
```

Comment: At least ask question properly with proper format.

Comment: use brackets () for your understanding,  `inquiry_time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' ) AND (inquiry_language LIKE '%$language%') AND (service.. `

Comment: That's a lot of conditions..have you tried executing on the DB directly? What does the actual query come out to be?

Comment: i not try to DB directly yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM quick_inquiry
WHERE (inquiry_time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')
AND inquiry_language LIKE '%$language%'
AND service_country LIKE '%$country%'
AND category LIKE '%$category%'
AND replied LIKE '%$replied%'
```

Also you can use >= and <=

```
SELECT * FROM quick_inquiry
WHERE inquiry_time >= '$start'
AND inquiry_time <= '$end'
AND inquiry_language LIKE '%$language%'
AND service_country LIKE '%$country%'
AND category LIKE '%$category%'
AND replied LIKE '%$replied%'
```

Comment: there is no change, you just copy and paste

Comment: You don't know what those variables are, this can't be answered currently,

Comment: $start should be the start value and $end should be the end value and for sure $end should be >= $start

Comment: Just missing my first (. See the updated answer please.

Comment: The parentheses do nothing here

Comment: @sqluser i have try this, but still not working, any another way??

Comment: If you are not getting any result, try to remove each condition one by one to see where the problem occurs. Also my second query is always better rather than using `BETWEEN`

Comment: @sqluser i try to remove inquiry_time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' running well, but when i put again, the result error again

Comment: When you say error, you mean no result. right? Anyway try to check if $start and $end are in correct date format and $end >= @start and also if you have data in that range

Comment: @sqluser in my database inquiry_time i using data time type data yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss, but in $start and $date just date yyyy-mm-dd. any effect on mysql query?

Comment: My suggestion is try to assign a value to your variables and run your query. With or without time. Let me know the result.